# SQL syntax error. Asking me to check the manual for MariaDB server

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm getting the error stating that

> Error inserting RecordYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''arcade',123)' at line 1"

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    //code to insert new record into DB
    $insQuery = "insert into inventory values(NULL,"
    ."'". $_POST['name'] ."',"
    . $_POST['price'] .","
    . $_POST['rating'] .","
    . $_POST['console'] .","
    ."'". $_POST['genre'] ."',"
    . $_POST['quantity'] .")";
```

Comment: You should echo out the value of `$insQuery` it will probably be pretty obvious where your syntax error is

Comment: i echo it . it gives me just this "insert into inventory values(NULL,'sonic',5.99,1,,'arcade',123)Error inserting RecordYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''arcade',123)' at line 1"

Comment: 1. Stop concataning user input into SQL. Parameterize the query. This WILL get you SQL injected. 2. Use PHP error reporting it seems like one of your POST indices is not populated, output your `$_POST` (`print_r($_POST)` and confirm. 3. You're likely to have better performance if you define the columns you are inserting into. You won't need the `NULL` if you do it that way

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Please read the basic php mysql document https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

```
//code to insert new record into DB
$insQuery = "insert into inventory(name, price,rating, console,gender,quantity) values(NULL, '". $_POST['name'] ."','"
. $_POST['price'] ."','"
. $_POST['rating'] ."','"
. $_POST['console'] ."','"
."','". $_POST['genre'] ."','"
. $_POST['quantity'] ."')";
```

U forgot some comma (,) and ' in ur query and also forgot table field name in inventory(name, price,rating, console,gender,quantity).... put it ut table field name there...